# Custom Headers with Express Swagger Generator?

Tags: javascript, api, express, authentication, swagger

I'm new to swagger, and use **express swagger generator** node module to make an API documentation.

The API use a string based key system, not APIkey.

The code I use to generate the documentation looks like this.

```
/**
 * Return merged data for a given landingPageId.
 * @route GET /merged/admin/{landingId}
 * @group Admin - Admin oriented operations
 * @param {string} landingId.path - ID of the needed landing page
 * @param {string} auth.header.required - Auth Key
 * @returns {object} 200 - Content of a landing page of the specified id
 * @returns {object} 401 - Unauthorized
 * @returns {Error}  default - error
 */
```

Question is : I can't use the swagger's auth because I'm not using APIKey, and I want to input my custom auth in header via express swagger, but "auth.header" does not work, is there a way to get through this ? Or do I need to go by Swagger itself in order to find a suitable solution ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

in the swagger options you must define them

> ```
>  securityDefinitions: {
>    JWT: {
>      type: 'apiKey',
>      in: 'header',
>      name: 'nameOfYourSec',
>      description: "Ensure Auth User Token"
>    }
>  }
> ```

then add the header:

> @headers {string} Authorization
> and the security
> @security JWT

Worked for me